# How do I override a single method in java class

Tags: java, android, methods

I am fairly new to java development and wounder how I can modify an existing Android class. I would like to change some of the methods in `Notification.Builder` class in Android (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Notification.java).

Specifically do I want to change `getNotification()`, but in the new implementation I need access to the private fields (e.g., `mWhen`, `mSmallIcon`).

I have tried to extend the class, but then I don't have access to the private fields of the superclass (i.e., `mWhen`, `mSmallIcon`).

What is the best practice to change the method, is it to copy the source code and modify it?

Update:
To be more precise: how can I change a single method in an existing class and still have access to the private fields of the existing class?

Thanks for all responses!

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: I have a dynamic icon (shows the temperature), I need a custom layout for the content and the ticker. I know that it could be done by giving a custom contentView and tickerView, but I would rather like to make a custom builder. Maybe its better to pass the views...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply call `super.getNotification()` in your overriden method and modify the resulting object before returning it.

Comment: Thanks, but then I still don't have access to the private field of Notification.Builder (e.g., mWhen)

Comment: @tibnor: Yes - but you don't need that because they exist only to set the public fields of Notification.

Answer (score 0):

A private (inner) class, method or field are only referenced from within the class in which it is declared.
But you also can declare your own variables and work with it as you wish

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is not to override methods (from third-party classes which were not designed to be overridden), but to create a new class/method which wraps the third-party class. Google for these: "fragile base class problem", "composition over inheritance".

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to extend the class, but then I don't have access to the private fields of the superclass (i.e., mWhen, mSmallIcon).

In the particular class you're extending there are a limited number of methods that set the values of these fields.  You can override those methods to hold onto copies of the values in new fields in your subclass which you can then use in your override of `getNotification()`.

This is something of a hack, and wouldn't be workable with a more complex class.

Another hack is to use reflection and invoke [`setAccessible(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29) on the field objects.  This also may not be workable depending on security constraints.

If you say exactly the change you're trying to make, there might be a better way.